# How to set size of Winform Scrollbar Arrow inside the rectangle C#

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

I am using "DrawArrowButton" method in my code and I can set the required size of the rectangle enclosing the Arrow but I cannot size the Arrow itself. My requirement is to increase the arrow height or width touch the rectangle side to side.
I am using the below code but I do not know how to resize the arrow.

```
Graphics g;
Rectangle rectLeftDown = new Rectangle(this.SplitterRectangle.Location, new Size(width, height));
ScrollBarArrowButtonState button1State = ScrollBarArrowButtonState.LeftNormal;
ScrollBarRenderer.DrawArrowButton(g, rectLeftDown, button1State);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Graphics.ScaleTransform Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhc2xxtx(v=vs.110).aspx) before drawing.

```
g.ScaleTransform(2, 2);
```

Now you can draw in double size (as an example).

Comment: @HansPassant: It's how transforms are supposed to work, unless the`ScrollBarRenderer` resets (temporarily) the transformation matrix.